# cpp-ethereum make error with json files

Tags: cpp-ethereum, bug

To install cpp-ethereum, I followed the below steps given in the ethereum community forum:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:george-edison55/cmake-3.x
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install language-pack-en-base
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
sudo apt-get -y install software-properties-common
wget -O - ://llvm.org/apt/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb //llvm.org/apt/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main"
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential git cmake libboost-all-dev libgmp-dev libleveldb-dev libminiupnpc-dev libreadline-dev libncurses5-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libcryptopp-dev libjson-rpc-cpp-dev libmicrohttpd-dev libjsoncpp-dev libargtable2-dev llvm-3.8-dev libedit-dev mesa-common-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 opencl-headers libgoogle-perftools-dev qtbase5-dev qt5-default qtdeclarative5-dev libqt5webkit5-dev libqt5webengine5-dev ocl-icd-dev libv8-dev
git clone ://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum-cmake
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/cpp-ethereum
cd cpp-ethereum
git checkout master
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make -j2
```

Everything is fine up to `cmake ..`

When I do the make then it build 10% percentage and giving the following errors:

```
CallInst *CreateCall(Function *Callee, ArrayRef<Value *> Args,
         ^
/usr/lib/llvm-3.8/include/llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h:1566:13: note:   no known 
conversion for argument 2 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>’
/home/iiita/cpp-ethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/Arith256.cpp: In member function 
‘llvm::Function* dev::eth::jit::Arith256::getExpFunc()’:
/home/iiita/cpp-ethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/Arith256.cpp:408:25: error: ‘class
llvm::Argument’ has no member named ‘getNextNode’
   auto exponent = base->getNextNode();
                         ^
make[2]: *** [evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/Array.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  8%] Built target scrypt
[  8%] Built target secp256k1
[  8%] Automatic moc for target ethash-cl
make[2]: *** [evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/Arith256.cpp.o] Error 1
[  8%] Built target ethash-cl_automoc
[  9%] Automatic moc for target ethash
[  9%] Built target ethash_automoc
[ 11%] Built target jsengine
[ 11%] [ 11%] Built target jsonrpcstub
Generating qrc_natspec.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target testeth_automoc
[ 12%] Scanning dependencies of target natspec
Automatic moc for target testeth
[ 12%] Built target testeth_automoc
Scanning dependencies of target createRandomTest_automoc
[ 13%] [ 13%] Building CXX object libnatspec/CMakeFiles/natspec.dir/NatspecExpressionEvaluator.cpp.o
Automatic moc for target createRandomTest
[ 13%] Built target createRandomTest_automoc
[ 13%] Generating qrc_js.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target jsqrc
[ 13%] Building CXX object libjsqrc/CMakeFiles/jsqrc.dir/qrc_js.cpp.o
Linking CXX static library libjsqrc.a
[ 13%] Built target jsqrc
[ 13%] Building CXX object libnatspec/CMakeFiles/natspec.dir/qrc_natspec.cpp.o
make[1]: *** [evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/**evmjit**.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Linking CXX shared library libnatspec.so
[ 13%] Built target natspec
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I read your installation instructions and *can only guess* you have found a *very old* resource. The ethereum forum is very old and a lot of dead weight can be found over there.

What you are looking for is the Ethereum Documentation which you can find here: http://www.ethdocs.org/

To install cpp-ethereum, all you need to do is the following:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cpp-ethereum
```

[Source](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/linux-ubuntu-ppa.html).

If you insist on building from source, please [follow this guide](http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/linux.html).